# How can I fix this error with my favicon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I deleted the generic file favicon.ico and replaced it with the favicon specific to the app I'm working on, which has the name 1.ico. In the head section of my application layout file, I inserted the following code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/1.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

When I open my application in my local environment, the favicon isn't visible, and I get the following response in my terminal:

Started GET "/public/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-16 13:33:22 -0400
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/public/favicon.ico"):

I'm not sure how I can fix this error, so any help would be great! I realize that there are a fair number of questions related to favicons, but after doing research I didn't find any questions or answers that were of help. Thanks!

Comment: What web server is this on? I would imagine that the root web directory is wrong.

Comment: I deleted the cache, and it still wasn't visible. I'm using Webrick as the server for my local environment!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the slash sign before `1.ico`.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="1.ico" type="image/ico" />
```

**EDIT**

Try using the [Favicon Rails](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag) helper:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag '1.ico' %>
```

Comment: I just tried it, and I got the following error: Started GET "/assets/1.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-16 14:48:41 -0400
Served asset /1.ico - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/1.ico"):       Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: another try: rename the icon to `favicon.ico`, place it on the public folder and include only `<%= favicon_link_tag %>` on the head.. Also delete the default rails favicon.ico that is automatically generated with every new rails app.

Comment: I did what you suggested, and stil got this error:   Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-16 15:16:48 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):   Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: Bueller? Did anyone crack this one? Having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

the path you pass to favicon_link_tag is probably incorrect. if your favicon is in the public directory, you want to pass '/path/from/public/favicon.ico', but if it's in the assets directory, you want to pass 'path/from/assets/favicon.ico'. note that there's no slash in the beginning